# Numeric Regular Expression for "optional sign, optional digits, optional dot, one or more digits"

Tags: regex

I've got a regular expression that I'm using for validating a decimal type number in .NET.

Current Regular Expression

```
 [-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

(EDIT - My problem was due to the Regular Expression `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]`:  I was missing the `+` at the end)

The SQL database I'm working with has the number defined as numeric(28,12), so I suppose I need to validate anything in that range, although by business logic enforces a value of 0 to 9,999.99.

So, while any data I put in using my validation will work for the business rules defined, I have to account for data already in the database, as it's fed by another system.

**I need all those numbers to validate:**

```
.5
0.5
450.000000000000  
.450
```

Comment: The original regex seems to work perfectly for .5 as well. Can't retrace it.

Comment: Based upon this regex testing site, http://regexhero.net/tester/, there is nothing wrong with my regular expression. Rather it seems there is a problem with Microsoft's Regular Expression Attribute data annotation. I'm going to re-post this question under MVC3 Validation.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex as you have it now should work fine.  Here is a walk through of each portion of the regex:

```
[-+]?   # matches '-' or '+', optional
[0-9]*  # matches zero or more digits, as many as possible
\.?     # matches a '.', optional
[0-9]+  # matches one or more digits, as many as possible
```

For ".5" the first two portions are missing, but that would not fail the match.  Not sure why you are having troubles but it could be with the .NET code, post it and we can try to help.

You may want to try escaping the "-" in your first character class (`[\-+]`), this shouldn't be necessary since the "-" is the first character, but when "-" is in a character class it usually specifies a range.

Comment: I don't require the [-+], so I will remove that from the expression

Comment: I tried removing the [-+] and it didn't like that. I then removed the [-+]? and it doesn't like that either.  Here is the expression I'm using now and the exception I'm getting.   parsing "[0-9]?*\.?[0-9]?[0-9]+" - Nested quantifier *.

Comment: You should definitely not have a `?*` anywhere in your regex.  `?` means "match one or zero times" and `*` means "match zero or more times".  One after the other is meaningless.

Comment: OK, FJ, I'm crediting you with the answer since you helped by breaking down the expression and that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

Escaping issue with the ".".

Comment: His "." was escaped, it just wasn't visible because of the formatting.

Comment: isn't that just the originally posted regex?

Comment: @phimuemue - He posted it before the question was edited, the originally posted regex was not formatted as code so the backslash wasn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
```

Actually pyroscope got it right with a + at the end instead of a *

Comment: This can also match an empty string, which may not be intended.

Comment: Acutually, your change led me to the problem. I was missing the + at the end on one of my validations. I'm validating multiple properties (using MVC3 Data Annotations RegularExpression validator). Anyway, in one of my instances, I left off the +.  Now does this fix the issue with all the 0's at the end, or the problem with the '.' leading without a zero?

Comment: The link you provided is where I got the original regex I'm using.  However, I don't need the +/- option. I do need to option to start the number with the decimal.  Perhaps I should change the original question.

Comment: Accepting an empty string is intended. The problem I have is that the underlying datatype is a decimal and not a string. If I change my backing field to a string, the regex works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The regex seems to be fine, however the processing afterwards (DB or whatever) may not accept this format.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\d` to represent digits.  This takes into account decimal numbers without leading numbers.

```
^[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)$
```

Also, the noncapturing groups `(?:regex)` make it perform better since the engine must do less capturing work.

Comment: @Jeff, is there a space in your ` .5`?

Comment: @Jeff, it works fine for me.  Are you escaping the `\`s in your regex appropriately for your language?