# Assistance with Regex regarding limiting alphabetical characters

Tags: javascript, html, regex, visual-studio

I am having some trouble setting up RegEx's. Could somebody help me in building a RegEx with these conditions:

Accepts only numbers (0-9)

Accepts a period (.), a negative sign (-), a plus sign (+), a dollar sign ($), and a comma (,)

Does not allow any alphabetical characters (a-z, A-Z)

Comment: You could try work from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948288/numeric-regular-expression-help. Or mentioned there in - http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html

Comment: I will take a look at this, thank you for the reply!

Comment: The answers given would work with the conditions you've given. But I wonder - I interpreted your question as if you wanted to match a positive or negative floating point amount ($) - was that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression

```
[0-9,.$\-\+]

0-9 a single character in the range between 0 (ASCII 48) and 9 (ASCII 57) 
,.$ matches a single character in the list ,.$
\- matches the character - literally 
\+ matches the character + literally
```

Comment: @k97513 Nope, not when in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

This regex expression works for me:

```
^[0-9$.,+-]+$
```

**Explanation:**

`^` matches the beginning of the string

`[]` A character set (matches characters listed)

`0-9` Any number from 0-9

`$` Matches a $ sign

`-` matches a - sign

`.` matches a .

`,` matches a ,

`+` matches a + sign

`+` One or more of the characters listed

`$` End of the string

You can test this [here](http://www.regex101.com/)

Comment: You don't need to escape the `-` or the `+` either, inside a character class. Just put the `-` first or last: `^[0-9$.,+-]+$`

Comment: Ah, OK. Updated post.